# php page not found for plugin options menu

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, pages, options

I'm trying to make an options page for a plugin and i'm getting The requested URL /site/wp-admin/plugin-email.php was not found on this server. every time i press 'Save settings'.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'settings_menu_email' );

function settings_menu_email() {
    add_options_page( 
        'Set Email', 
        'Set Email', 
        'manage_options', 
        'set-email', 
        'display_set_email_settings'
    );

    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_set_email_options' );
}

function register_set_email_options() {
    register_setting( 'set-email-option-group', 'set-email' );
}

function display_set_email_settings() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Schimba email</h1>

    <?php settings_fields( 'set-email-option-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'set-email-option-group' ); ?>

    <form method="post" action="plugin-email.php">
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Email</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="set-email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('set-email') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php  submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
    </div>
```

I tried making an options.php file, but i get the same thing.

Comment: where exactly is your file plugin-email.php located in your WordPress installation?

Comment: /wp-content/plugins/plugin-email, i tried to link the full path, still get error The requested URL /site/wp-contet/plugins/plugin-email/plugin-email.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at an old commit on a plugin I am writing, I am seeing a couple of things that jump out at me.

First is your options page declaration. I had mine as follows, using your labels:

```
function settings_menu_email() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Set Email',
        'Set Email',
        'manage_options',
        'email_admin_menu',
        'email_admin_menu_callback',
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'email_admin_menu',
        __( 'Options', 'textdomain' ),
        __( 'Options', 'textdomain' ),
        'administrator',
        'email_admin_menu_options',
        'email_admin_menu_options_callback'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'settings_menu_email' );
```

Then define your settings groups outside of the callback function.

```
function email_initialize_plugin_options() {
    add_settings_section(
        'email_settings_section',
        'EMail Options',
        'email_options_callback',
        'email_admin_menu_options'
    );

    // Add Email Address Option
    add_settings_field(
        'email_settings_section',
        'EMail Address',
        'email_set_address_callback',
        'email_admin_menu_options',
        'email_settings_section',
        array(
            'Enter a description here...',
        )
    );

    // Register Email Address Option
    register_setting(
        'email_settings_section',
        'email_settings_section'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'email_initialize_plugin_options' );
```

Then you do your callbacks.

In order to test this, just add empty callback functions.